# Connect to Exchange server with IMAP from GMail

Tags: email, gmail, exchange, imap, gmail-imap

At the moment I have an exchange account. All mail then gets forwarded to a GMail account. I have set that account up so I can send email from the exchange account so it looks as if I sent it from that account not the GMail account.

The exchange server now has IMAP and so when I read an email in GMail I want it to be marked as read back on the exchange server.

Is that possible?

**UPDATE:** I've just done some more research and it looks like you cannot use Gmail as a email client to check IMAP enabled email accounts. How rubbish!

Comment: What version of Exchange do you have and what os

Comment: Its Exchange 2003 / Windows 2003 Server